# How to remove a subsection of data while using filter() in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have my data frame `p`.

**Question:** how can I exclude a subsection of my filtered data with a specific condition? The solution must be in `dplyr` as I am trying to learn this package.

I have

```
> head(p)
  studie id alder contra.pos ecs lnd n.fjernet n.sygdom uicc
1      2  1    47          0   0 0.0        22        1    4
2      2  2    50          0   0 0.0        61        2    4
3      2  3    61          0   0 0.0        50        1    4
4      2  4    83          0   1 0.1        47        3    4
5      2  5    38          0   0 0.0        30        1    3
6      2  6    44          0   0 0.0        60        0    4
```

And

```
> table(p$uicc)

  1   2   3   4 
321 231 248 720
```

With

```
> table(p$studie)

  2   3   4   5   6 
221  40 641 464 154
```

How can I completely remove patients with the condition `studie==4 & uicc %in% 1:3`? For me, the tricky part is too add the removal within the `filter()-function`

```
p %>% mutate(lnd = round(n.sygdom/n.fjernet,1),
             positive = ifelse(n.sygdom>0,1,0)) %>%
           filter(n.fjernet > 0,
                  lnd<100,
                  studie %in% 2:6,
                  !str_detect(studie==4 & uicc %in% 1:3)) %>%
           na.omit
```

I also tried `... !(studie==4 & uicc %in% 1:3)...`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `str_detect`? Couldn't you just do `!(studie==4 & uicc %in% 1:3)`

Comment: That is odd. I tried that, as it says in the question, but it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

`p %>% filter(studie != 4 & uicc == 4)`

?